# RandomizedSearchCV with Keras LSTM (Regression)

Tags: python, keras

I'm trying to tune hyperparameters for LSTM using RandomizedSearchCV. My code:

```
train_X, train_y = train[:, :-1], train[:, -1]
train_X = train_X.reshape((train_X.shape[0], timesteps, features))


def create_model(neurons =50, hidden_layers=1):
    model = Sequential()
    model.add(LSTM(neurons, 
                   return_sequences = True, 
                   input_shape=(train_X.shape[1], train_X.shape[2])))
    model.add(Dropout(0.2))
    for i in range(hidden_layers):
        model.add(LSTM(neurons))
        model.add(Dropout(0.2))

    model.add(Dense(1))
    model.compile(loss='mean_squared_error', optimizer='adam', metrics=['acc'])
    return model

my_regressor = KerasRegressor(build_fn=create_model, verbose=0)

# Create hyperparameter space
epochs = [100, 150]
batches = [5, 10]
hidden_layers = [1, 2]
neurons = [50, 100]

hyperparameters = dict(neurons=neurons,
                       epochs=epochs, 
                       batch_size=batches, 
                       hidden_layers = hidden_layers)

grid = RandomizedSearchCV(estimator=my_regressor, 
                          param_distributions=hyperparameters)


# Fit grid search


grid_result = grid.fit(train_X, train_y)
```

This throws the error:

> ValueError: Input 0 is incompatible with layer lstm_93: expected ndim=3, found ndim=2

Any idea what I am doing wrong here?

Comment: look here: `input_shape=(train_X.shape[1], train_X.shape[2])`. You should input all dimensions of your `train_X`, i.e. 3.

Comment: @VitaliAvagyan When i add the third dimension ( `input_shape=(train_X.shape[0], train_X.shape[1], train_X.shape[2]))` ), python throws 
"Input 0 is incompatible with layer lstm_4: expected ndim=3, found ndim=4"

Comment: Try with `return_sequences = False`.

Comment: Thanks again, but i'm still getting the same error.

Comment: Ok. I will inspect this later in more detail when I find some time. Meanwhile, when you are sequentially adding layers, you should make sure that one layer output dimension speaks with the next layer input dimension.

Comment: Can you give me your data? What is your train?